# Full Calendar Not A Function CDN

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

Currently in my project i am trying to implement full calendar onto my page. However there is not much writing about it online using CDN however i refer to libman in the project a lot so id prefer to use CDN.

The current issue is it's flagging in DOM that fullCalendar is not defined when it is.

LAYOUT.CSHTML

```
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/fullcalendar/core/main.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<div class="shadow-lg content-card bg-white rounded text-center">

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

[image]

Comment: That syntax is for fullCalendar version 3. You're using version 4, or at least so it would appear (from the reference to "core" and "main.js"). Refer to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals (and/or any of the CodePen demos linked from various places in the fullCalendar documentation) to see the correct syntax for v4 - also take note of which other files and settings are required, at minimum, for it to work. P.S. I guess you found this example on some older tutorial or forum post or something, and used it without referring to the official documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was you have to use more files from the lib. If anyone else is struggling refer to the examples that the page provides as the getting started code on the website is poor and does not provide adequate installation support.